# MySQL 8.0.22 Trigger won't run unless definer is logged in

Tags: mysql, trigger, ubuntu

I have the following tigger that used to work before upgrading to MySQL 8 from MySQL 5.  Now the trigger will only run if the definer is logged in via phpmyadmin or some other database admin tool. The trigger is setup as timing After and event Insert.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `countupdate` AFTER INSERT ON `status`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET @COUNT=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `status` WHERE status.`systemname`= NEW.`systemname`);
       IF @COUNT > 0 THEN 
        IF NEW.`status` = 'UP'
        THEN 
        UPDATE `updowncount`
        SET `upcount` = `upcount` +1, lastupdate = NOW()
        WHERE systemname = NEW.`systemname`;
        ELSE
        UPDATE `updowncount`
        SET `downcount` = `downcount` +1, lastupdate = NOW()
        WHERE systemname = NEW.`systemname`;
        END IF;
    END IF;
 END
```

I have tried deleting the trigger then creating it again and setting the definer to `root@%`. I also tried definer `root@localhost`.

Running on Ubuntu 20.04.1

**UPDATE:**
Also it appears that I have to go back in and re-save the trigger or it won't trigger.

Log file during an insert that did not update data based on the tigger:

```
2020-12-14T02:06:09.569622Z   794 Query INSERT INTO status (systemname, status, lastchecked) VALUES ('Linuxdb2', 'Up', '2020-12-13 20:06:09.569394')
2020-12-14T02:06:09.569808Z   794 Query SET @COUNT=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `updowncount` WHERE updowncount.`systemname`= NEW.`systemname`)
2020-12-14T02:06:09.570132Z   794 Query SET @COUNT=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `status` WHERE status.`systemname`= NEW.`systemname`)
2020-12-14T02:06:09.574412Z   794 Query COMMIT
```

When status table has a new row inserted two tiggers run. The one above that has stopped working and one to add the system to the updowncount table. If the systemname doesn't exist in updowncount table.  This is a before for insert trigger.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `countsystemadd` BEFORE INSERT ON `status`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
       SET @COUNT=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `updowncount` WHERE updowncount.`systemname`= NEW.`systemname`);
       IF @COUNT=0 THEN
        INSERT INTO `updowncount` (upcount, downcount, systemname, `lastupdate`) VALUES (0, 0, NEW.`systemname`, NOW());
       END IF;
END
```

Thirteen new rows are all added with in seconds of each other by different python scripts.

Status table:

```
CREATE TABLE `status` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `systemname` char(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` char(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastchecked` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=444 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Updowncount table:

```
CREATE TABLE `updowncount` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `upcount` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `downcount` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `systemname` text,
  `lastupdate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**UPDATE:**
I removed the `countsystemadd` trigger and things started working. But once the data in the `status` table gets over 1,000 records the it stops working. This what shows up in the log.

```
2021-01-08T15:00:01.829948Z  1348 Query INSERT INTO status (systemname, status, lastchecked) VALUES ('msmccam', 'Up', '2021-01-08 09:00:01.829712')
2021-01-08T15:00:01.830210Z  1348 Query SET @COUNT=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `status` WHERE status.`systemname`= NEW.`systemname`)
2021-01-08T15:00:01.831031Z  1348 Query COMMIT
```

Comment: so when you loged ln as another user and insert a row, it doesn't run the trigger? without an error or log entry?

Comment: @nbk No, I have updated the question with additional information based on your question.

Comment: Please provide complete and unchanged trigger creation script, not the body only. Also provide DLL for the tables involved and the statement which must fire the trigger.

Comment: everything is running, you have zwei trigger s one for staus and one for updowncount that look similar, and i think the ne for updowncount skips the update

Comment: @Akina I don't have creation script as I used phpmyadmin add trigger to create it. I am not sure what you mean by DLL for the tables.  See update.

Comment: *I don't have creation script as I used phpmyadmin add trigger to create it.* Obtain it using [SHOW CREATE TRIGGER Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-trigger.html). *I am not sure what you mean by DLL for the tables.* The output of [SHOW CREATE TABLE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html).

Comment: @nbk See update

Comment: @Akina I have made the updates. Thank you for being helpful.

Comment: I convert your codes to a fiddle. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b13a44c7cb33ce0c946b879207c051b4 You may add the link to the question instead of codes - it is more useful. PS. I'll try to reproduce your issue.Now I cannot imagine the reason of it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine, with  your triggers, as long as you don't have also a Trgger on `updowncount`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `status` (
>   `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `systemname` char(40) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `status` char(40) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `lastchecked` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=444 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `updowncount` (
>   `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `upcount` int DEFAULT NULL,
>   `downcount` int DEFAULT NULL,
>   `systemname` text,
>   `lastupdate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
> ```

> ```
>  CREATE TRIGGER `countsystemadd` BEFORE INSERT ON `status`
>  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
>        SET @COUNT=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `updowncount` WHERE updowncount.`systemname`= NEW.`systemname`);
>        IF @COUNT=0 THEN
>         INSERT INTO `updowncount` (upcount, downcount, systemname, `lastupdate`) VALUES (0, 0, NEW.`systemname`, NOW());
>        END IF;
> END
> ```

> ```
>  CREATE TRIGGER `countupdate` AFTER INSERT ON `status`
>  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
>     SET @COUNT=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `status` WHERE status.`systemname`= NEW.`systemname`);
>        IF @COUNT > 0 THEN 
>         IF NEW.`status` = 'UP'
>         THEN 
>         UPDATE `updowncount`
>         SET `upcount` = `upcount` +1, lastupdate = NOW()
>         WHERE systemname = NEW.`systemname`;
>         ELSE
>         UPDATE `updowncount`
>         SET `downcount` = `downcount` +1, lastupdate = NOW()
>         WHERE systemname = NEW.`systemname`;
>         END IF;
>     END IF;
>  END
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO status (`systemname`,`status`) VALUES  ('SystemA','UP')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM updowncount
> ```
>
> ```
> id | upcount | downcount | systemname | lastupdate         
> -: | ------: | --------: | :--------- | :------------------
> 18 |       1 |         0 | SystemA    | 2020-12-15 19:18:43
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e84bb360f9258236f8e2dcae0ed8c344)*

Comment: See update as the trigger has stopped working.

Comment: I run the code on my workstation, with 1848 INSERTS and it runs withouit a problem. so you must search for anathor reason like timeouts